# At what version of AngularJS was the '=?' isolate scope introduced?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, version

What version of AngularJS introduced the '=?' scope definition?

ie:

```
...
.directive('exampleDirective', [ function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            foo: '=?'
        },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was introduced in 1.1.4.

Here's a link to Angular's change log: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-46

And the change itself: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ac899d0da59157fa1c6429510791b6c3103d9401